# How to pass two string arrays as one parameter android/java

Tags: java, android

I have these two String arrays,

```
String[] from = { "name" };
String[] favourite = { "favourite" };
```

Which I want to pass into this constructor:

```
      contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_list_item, null, HERE, to);
```

Where it says HERE. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You'd need to create a new array with the content of both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate two string array into one single string array

```
String[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use any collection framework.
As your requirement for two value pair data structure.
I suggest you to use hashmap with key - value pair.

```
HashMap(String from, String favourite);
```

And use custom adopter instead of SimpleCursorAdapter.